MVVM - Binding Property uses class but value stays empty
Thanks for reading into my issue.
I just started working with C# MAUI MVVM and ran into the following issue:
DetailPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.DetailPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:DetailViewModel"
             Title="DetailPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="20">
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Text}"
            FontSize="25"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Go Back" Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}" />
        <Image Source="{Binding Uri.normal}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

DetailViewModel.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MauiApp2.Model;

namespace MauiApp2.ViewModel
{
    [QueryProperty("Text", "Text")]
    [QueryProperty("Normal", "Normal")]
    [QueryProperty("ImageUris.normal", "ImageUris.normal")]
    public partial class DetailViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        string text;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string normal;
        [ObservableProperty]
        Cards_Root.ImageUris uri;



        [RelayCommand]
        async Task GoBack()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
    }
}

Used Classes from Cards_Root look like this
public class Cards_Root 
{
    public ImageUris image_uris { get; set; }
}

public class ImageUris
{
    public string small { get; set; }
    public string normal { get; set; }
    public string large { get; set; }
    public string png { get; set; }
    public string art_crop { get; set; }
    public string border_crop { get; set; }
}

The Binding of "Text" on the Label in DetailPage works fine, but the Source of the Image stays empty and I cant figure out why. First thought it might be because of the name of the Variable, but Visual Studio even highlights it as using "Uri" as ImageUris Class and "normal" as string.
Thanks a lot in Advance!

what is Cards_Root.ImageUris? It should be ImageUris as the ObservableProperty Type.

You are using QueryProperty incorrectly.

@PrabhavMehra Cards_Root is the name of the Model where ImageUri is class from, changed it now, but didnt change any behaviour

@Jason could you explain why? I tried to do it the same way like Text, but doesnt seem to work that way obviously

because your VM does not have a property named ImageUris.normal

normal is a Property in ImageUris class. I understand you may want to change the normal value. But instead of passing the normal property, you may pass the Uri instance, like the following code,
...
[QueryProperty("Uri", "ImageUris")]
public partial class DetailViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    ...
    [ObservableProperty]
    ImageUris uri;

when performing shell navigation,
        ImageUris imageUris = new ImageUris();
        imageUris.Normal = "dotnet_bot.png";

        var navigationParameter = new ShellNavigationQueryParameters
        { 
            {"Text",Text},
            {"Normal", Normal},
            {"ImageUris",imageUris }
        };

        Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"Details", navigationParameter);

Another thing that should be noted is that, the normal property of ImageUris class should also be ObservableProperty. Otherwise, the UI will not change though the value has been changed.
public partial class ImageUris:ObservableObject
{
    ...

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string normal;
    ...
}

Now you may use the Binding for Image Source
<Image Source="{Binding Uri.Normal}"/>

For more info, you may refer to .NET MAUI Shell navigation.
